# Java 8 Stream Matrix Multiplication 10X Slower Than For Loop?

Tags: java, math, java-8, benchmarking, java-stream

I have created a module that performs matrix multiplication using streams.  It can be found here:
https://github.com/firefly-math/firefly-math-linear-real/

I've attempted to write a benchmark in order to compare the stream loop implementation to the corresponding for loop implementation in Apache Commons Math.

The benchmark module is here:
https://github.com/firefly-math/firefly-math-benchmark

And the actual benchmark here:
https://github.com/firefly-math/firefly-math-benchmark/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fireflysemantics/benchmark/MultiplyBenchmark.java

When I run the benchmark on matrices sized 100X100 and 1000X1000 it turns out that Apache Commons Math (Uses a for loop) is 10X faster (Roughly) than the corresponding stream implementation.

```
# Run complete. Total time: 00:14:10

Benchmark                              Mode  Cnt      Score     Error      Units
MultiplyBenchmark.multiplyCM1000_1000  avgt   30   1040.804 ±  11.796  ms/op
MultiplyBenchmark.multiplyCM100_100    avgt   30      0.790 ±   0.010  ms/op
MultiplyBenchmark.multiplyFM1000_1000  avgt   30  11981.228 ± 405.812  ms/op
MultiplyBenchmark.multiplyFM100_100    avgt   30      7.224 ±   0.685  ms/op
```

Did I do something wrong in the benchmark (Hopefully :) )?

I'm adding the methods tested such that everyone can see what is being compared.  This is the Apache Commons Math Array2DRowRealMatrix.multiply() method:

```
/**
 * Returns the result of postmultiplying {@code this} by {@code m}.
 *
 * @param m matrix to postmultiply by
 * @return {@code this * m}
 * @throws DimensionMismatchException if
 * {@code columnDimension(this) != rowDimension(m)}
 */
public Array2DRowRealMatrix multiply(final Array2DRowRealMatrix m)
    throws DimensionMismatchException {
    MatrixUtils.checkMultiplicationCompatible(this, m);

    final int nRows = this.getRowDimension();
    final int nCols = m.getColumnDimension();
    final int nSum = this.getColumnDimension();

    final double[][] outData = new double[nRows][nCols];
    // Will hold a column of "m".
    final double[] mCol = new double[nSum];
    final double[][] mData = m.data;

    // Multiply.
    for (int col = 0; col < nCols; col++) {
        // Copy all elements of column "col" of "m" so that
        // will be in contiguous memory.
        for (int mRow = 0; mRow < nSum; mRow++) {
            mCol[mRow] = mData[mRow][col];
        }

        for (int row = 0; row < nRows; row++) {
            final double[] dataRow = data[row];
            double sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < nSum; i++) {
                sum += dataRow[i] * mCol[i];
            }
            outData[row][col] = sum;
        }
    }

    return new Array2DRowRealMatrix(outData, false);
}
```

And this is the corresponding stream implementation:

```
/**
 * Returns a {@link BinaryOperator} that multiplies {@link SimpleMatrix}
 * {@code m1} times {@link SimpleMatrix} {@code m2} (m1 X m2).
 * 
 * Example {@code multiply(true).apply(m1, m2);}
 * 
 * @param parallel
 *            Whether to perform the operation concurrently.
 * 
 * @throws MathException
 *             Of type {@code MATRIX_DIMENSION_MISMATCH__MULTIPLICATION} if
 *             {@code m} is not the same size as {@code this}.
 * 
 * @return the {@link BinaryOperator} that performs the operation.
 */
public static BinaryOperator<SimpleMatrix> multiply(boolean parallel) {

    return (m1, m2) -> {
        checkMultiplicationCompatible(m1, m2);

        double[][] a1 = m1.toArray();
        double[][] a2 = m2.toArray();

        Stream<double[]> stream = Arrays.stream(a1);
        stream = parallel ? stream.parallel() : stream;

        final double[][] result =
                stream.map(r -> range(0, a2[0].length)
                        .mapToDouble(i -> range(0, a2.length).mapToDouble(j -> r[j]
                                * a2[j][i]).sum())
                        .toArray()).toArray(double[][]::new);

        return new SimpleMatrix(result);
    };
}
```

TIA,
Ole

Comment: Is there a difference, as in interpreted languages, between explicit loops and the implicit loops hidden by `apply`? Is the compiler capable of optimizing away all the calls used in the implementation of the `apply` functionality? Calls to (virtual?) functions are expensive.

Comment: @Holger `toArray` is a simple field accessor. I get [similar results after having simplified the test](https://bitbucket.org/assylias/performance/src/master/src/main/java/com/assylias/performance/SO35037893.java). My guess is data locality and cache misses - there may be more to it...

Comment: The toArray() method on the stream implementation returns the double[][] array reference attached to the SimpleMatrix.  It could easily be named getData().  Just want to make it clear that it does not actually perform any mapping from on representation to another.  Also in general both implementations access a double[][].  The main difference is that streams vs. non streams.  Even with parallel turned on, the for loop is twice as fast.

Comment: I find the results still very weird. I'll run that benchmark as soon as I have the possibility.

Comment: Thanks @Tunaki.  I'm really hoping the tire just needs a little air or something :).

Comment: @assylias thanks for doing the rewrite and corresponding link.  Very impressive.

Comment: @assylias: `DoubleStream.sum()` uses an error compensation algorithm which likely is more expensive than a naive summing loop. However, I wouldn’t expect factor ten though. Regarding locality, unlike Apache’s math library, your loop variant does nothing to improve data locality.

Comment: @Holger Well spotted - not using `DoubleStream::sum` improves performance by 30% - now ratio is "only" 6x times slower vs 8x slower with the original version.

Comment: @assylias: you can get some percent more by reading the array lengths into local variables like you do in the loop variant and also `a2` (its easier for hotspot to eliminate unnecessary re-reads of the `a2` field in the loop variant compared to a lambda instance re-reading the field via a captured `this` instance).

Comment: @Holger yup another 20% - I would have thought the JIT would do that to be honest. Now 4.5x slower...

Comment: I've played around with it as well and it almost seems that no matter what the for Apache for loop is the best implementation, which makes me believe that I should be sticking to the for loop in general and just forget about parallel streams, as has been recommended by several of you?

Comment: Well, [I've run a similar benchmark](https://gist.github.com/Tunaki/f8de7bab6bde443fe130) and I confirm that the Stream version is 4.5x slower than the for loop version. Ran in parallel and for bigger matrices, it is somewhat better, it is only 2x slower... I'd still like to hear what causes this. I'd expect slower performance but not 4.5x slower.

Comment: Indeed.  I was thinking perhaps slightly slower for the single threaded version, but faster for the parallel version.  At this point it looks like anything but a for loop is a loosing proposition as far as performance goes.

Comment: I also tried benchmarking some of the more simple operations, like Array2dRealMatrix.getTrace() vs. MatrixOperations.trace(true) and the for loop still wins, even with the parallel switch turned on.

Comment: @Tunaki : you’re still using `DoubleStream.sum()` with error compensation instead of, e.g. `reduce(0,Double::sum)`…

Comment: @Holger Yeah actually I ran it with both possibilites `.sum()` and `.reduce(0, Double::sum)` and it didn't change much in the results I got (which is also weird since there was a 30% increase in performance for assylias...).

Comment: I created a new branch for the stream implementation.  I'll change the master to a regular for loop implementation.  This is the stream branch just for historical purposes: https://github.com/firefly-math/firefly-math-linear-real/tree/streams

Comment: It turns out my answer was wrong. I'd appreciate if you unaccepted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `DoublePipeline.toArray`:

```
public final double[] toArray() {
  return Nodes.flattenDouble((Node.OfDouble) evaluateToArrayNode(Double[]::new))
                    .asPrimitiveArray();
}
```

It seems that a boxed array is created first which is then converted to a primitive array.

Comment: It seems that this function is only there to fulfill the internal interface (or perhaps will be used when `boxed()` has been called). When doing a step by step debugging, you’ll see that this generator is not being used in this case. The returned node will contain a `double[]` array and since this stream has a fixed size, `asPrimitiveArray()` will directly return it.

Comment: @Holger Thanks for the update. I'll take a look at it and remove the answer if it's wrong. Maybe the slowdown is caused by the large amount of streams that are created then.

Comment: The answer is actually incorrect. This generator is not used after that. It's passed `AP::evaluateToArrayNode` -> `AP::evaluate` -> `DP::makeNodeBuilder` where it's just ignored.